# File not found on File with spaces in path

Tags: c++

How to enclose this with double quotes:

```
wsprintfW(szBuffer, L"%s\\cmd.exe /c start \"%s\\cmd.exe\" %s", szSystemDirectory, szSystemDirectory, lpCommandLine);
```

Solved

LR"(%s\cmd.exe /c start "%s\cmd.exe" "%s)"

Comment: You almost certainly *don't* need to specify "szSystemDirectory" in order to use "cmd.exe": Windows should find it automatically.

Comment: yes sure but not in my project trust me

Comment: OK - then what's wrong with the `\"` syntax to add double quotes to your format string?  The *same syntax you're already using* for `start \"%s\\cmd.exe\"`?

Comment: because my problem in here " %s" this will get me the application path like this %userprofile%\Desktop\mypro 3.2\rufus-2.5.exe in combobox and must be with enclose this with double Quote

Comment: `L"\"%s\\cmd.exe\" /c` ...

Comment: L"\"%s\\cmd.exe\" /c not working

Comment: You're making this an *AWFUL* lot harder than it needs to be.  The problem(s) are really very simple: 1) If you've got a path with embedded spaces, the solution is to quote (`"`) the path.  2) If you want quotes in your format string, the solution is to escape (`\"`) the quotes.  3) If you want to expand a variable, you can do so with `getenv()`, 4) there's absolutely no need to specify a filepath for cmd.exe on the vast majority of Windows environments, 5) I can't think of any reason  for "cmd.exe" twice in the same string.  And if you must, I would expect you to quote both the same.

Comment: Solved like this: wsprintfW(szBuffer, LR"(%s\cmd.exe /c start "%s\cmd.exe" "%s)", szSystemDirectory, szSystemDirectory, lpCommandLine);  thanks for everyone tried to help

Comment: Minor fix capitalizaton, removed tag from title